# How to query intermediate relationships in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, orm, laravel-5.4

I want to make a relationship queries on the three tables I have `tblSchedule` `tblUserHomeCourt` and `tblHomeCourt`

they have following structure

```
tblSchedules
->scheduleId
->userHomeCourtId
->timeFrom
->timeTo
->duration

tblUserHomeCourts
->userHomeCourtId
->userId
->homeCourtId

tblHomeCourts
->homeCourtId
->homeCourtName
->lat
->long and other details
```

Now, schedule will store the schedules of an user whereas userHomeCourts will store the current active homeCourt and homeCourt will provide the list of available homecourts.

how to fetch these details for a user?

in my schedule model I have tried `hasManyThrough` but it's giving me empty array of schedule

```
public function schedule() {

    return $this->hasManyThrough(HomeCourt::class,UserHomeCourt::class, 'homeCourtId', 'homeCourtId','scheduleId');
}
```

Comment: can you share your code what you have done so far ?

Comment: Do you have any models set up for these tables?

Comment: yeah I have models for each and every tables. and in schedule  model i have add hasManyThrough relationship but none I got see the edits

Comment: you should try hasMany with HomeCourt and UserHomeCourt and UserHomeCourt with belongs to users table

Comment: can you please post it as your answer?

Comment: so basically you want to access the user information from tblUserHomeCourts ?

Comment: i want to send these info as schedule is fetched to visible schedules of an user

Comment: i think you want to save the scheduleId in tblUserHomeCourts

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144909/discussion-between-bhavik-bamania-and-kunal).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, In your Schedule.php eloquent model class,

```
public function schedule(){
    return $this->hasMany(UserHomeCourt::class,'userHomeCourtId')->with('user_information')->with('home_courts');

}
```

In UserHomeCourt.php Model class

```
public function user_information(){
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'userId');
}
public function home_courts(){
    return $this->belongsTo(HomeCourt::class,'homeCourtId');
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: i think you database structure is not right and more complex

Comment: yeah you were right there I was just bit my mistake I got the right answer

Comment: always use normalization techniques (Y)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code, i usually using this method to make relationship

```
DB::table('tblSchedules')->join('tblUserHomeCourts', 'tblSchedules.userHomeCourtId', '=', 'tblUserHomeCourts.userHomeCourtId')
                        ->join('tblHomeCourts', 'tblUserHomeCourts.homeCourtId', '=', 'tblHomeCourts.homeCourtId')
                        ->get();
```